# how to make retrofit POJO class for this Json

Tags: java, android, kotlin

here is the json form that i try to make pojo class for it

```
 [{"ID":"1",
"SectionName":""
,"Title":"testosss"}
,{"ID":"2"
,"SectionName":"",
"Title":"test"}]
```

i have one array with list of object what should i do to make pojo class in this case ?

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: how to make retrofit  pojo class for this json form ?

Comment: go to file->setting->plugins-> find gson formater-> install and then  restart android studio then create class and use alt+enter select gson formater , copy all json paste the json in gson formater,  it will automatically create a pojo for you

Comment: The question and all comments from the OP make it even more confusing - what do you need? What is wrong with the answer given?

Comment: how to make pojo class to these json form in the above ,,all the solution didn't notice that there is tow object that have same  tag how to call tow ID withe different value in one ID in class ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate pojo class using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

private String iD;
private String sectionName;
private String title;

  public Example(){
  }

  public Example(String id,String sectionName,String title){
      this.iD = id;
      this.sectionName = sectionName;
      this.title = title;
  }
  public String getID() {
     return iD;
  }

  public void setID(String iD) {
     this.iD = iD;
  }

 public String getSectionName() {
    return sectionName;
 }

 public void setSectionName(String sectionName) {
    this.sectionName = sectionName;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
    return title;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
 }


}
```

Comment: it will not work because we have tow id in json from which value will call when u call id and etc

Comment: bro in jsom form in above how many id in side the json ? tow right ?

Comment: so how can i get each one Separately ?in pojo class u write its only one id we need to make list of id so we could get both id 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

whenever you have multiple jsonArray value in your json data, we need to store all data in ArrayList. here i have make some code for you i hope might be helpful you.

Your json data

```
     String jsonDemo = "[{\"ID\":\"1\",\n" +
                "\"SectionName\":\"\"\n" +
                ",\"Title\":\"testosss\"}\n" +
                ",{\"ID\":\"2\"\n" +
                ",\"SectionName\":\"\",\n" +
                "\"Title\":\"test\"}]";
```

for get josn data and store in ArrayList with Example pojo class
create ArrayList class with pojo model class

```
ArrayList<Example> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

json parsing and store each data in arraylist

```
 try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDemo);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String ID = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                String sectionName = jsonObject.getString("SectionName");
                String title = jsonObject.getString("Title");

                arrayList.add(new Example(ID,sectionName,title));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Retrieve all json data

```
 if(arrayList.size()>0){
            for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                Example example = arrayList.get(i);
                Log.d("Example","ID : " + example.getID());
                Log.d("Example","getSectionName : " + example.getSectionName());
                Log.d("Example","getTitle : " + example.getTitle());
            }
        }
```